# Ngx-bootstrap Error as self.context.openModal.template is not a function for Modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typescript, angular2-forms, ngx-bootstrap

Here im using ngx-bootstrap for modal for that i'm using his first modal example from ngx-bootstrap website..why i'm not able 2 open my template This is My code

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openModal.template()">Create template modal</button>

<template #template>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Modal</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRef.hide()">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        This is a modal.
    </div>
</template>
```

**Module.ts**

```
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
  imports: [AlertModule.forRoot(), ModalModule.forRoot()]
```

**Component.ts**

```
import { BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/';
    public modalRef: BsModalRef;
 constructor( private modalService: BsModalService){}
 openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
       debugger;
        this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're incorrectly calling `openModal` method.
This `openModal.template()` presumes that `openModal` is an object or class instance which has `template()` method.

Correct way would be `openModal(template)`